# How is this an extraneous solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say we've got $\sqrt{4-3x} = x$.

Now let's say we have $x = 1,-4$.

Let's punch $-4$ in first.

We wind up with $\pm4 = -4$.

> How is this an extraneous solution, but plugging in 1 isn't? Isn't a +- equal to negatives and positives?

Comment: The most common convention, at least in calculus courses, is that $\sqrt{16}$ is the *non-negative* number whose square is $16$. Other conventions are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the thing. A square root, when placed by itself, isn't negative, unless you put a "minus" in front of it. However, if your original equation was $x^2 = 4-3x$, both solutions would work. The confusion here arrives from you believing that $\sqrt{16}$ can be both positive and negative. Unless otherwise stated, $\sqrt{16}$ is always $4$, not $-4$, and so $4$ doesn't equal $-4$.

Comment: Why is that then? I don't understand how, logically, you can ever say it's positive because even if you're not solving for a variable, and it's just the square root by itself, it can still be negative or positive. Right?

Comment: @CollegeAnon We do this so that $\sqrt{x}$ is a *function*. Functions only give us one output (here, the positive square root of $x$) for a given input (here, $x$). If $\sqrt{x}$ meant "either the positive, or negative, square root of $x$", then it wouldn't be a function. We do this because we like functions very much (and using $\pm$, we can still get the negative root if we need it). [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729491/why-do-we-limit-the-definition-of-a-function/729522#729522) might provide more context.

Comment: I kinda get what that guy is saying, though I don't understand how saying something is equal to both -3 and 3 means 3 = -3. Unless saying +-3 = -3 is like saying both 3 and -3 equal -3?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5):

You need to be careful how you write the equation.  I'm assuming it is
$$\sqrt{4-3x}=x\ ,$$
as someone else has edited it.

In this case, remember that $\sqrt{a}$ denotes specifically the *positive* square root.  It isn't plus-or-minus unless you actually write it as $\pm\sqrt a\,$.  So substituting $x=-4$ gives
$$\sqrt{16}=-4\ ,$$
that is,
$$4=-4\ ,$$
which is not true.

Comment: Don't you always do +- (forgive me for not using symbols, as I don't know how to do that on here) with square root? Because sqrt(16) can either be -4^2 or 4^2.

Comment: With the square root symbol, as in $\sqrt{16}$, it is always positive.  However that's not the same as solving $x^2=16$, in which case the answer is $x=\pm\sqrt{16}=\pm4$.

Comment: So only when you get a square root when solving for x the +- comes into play?

Comment: I guess, though I'm not sure I would put it that way.  The point is that some equations, particularly those involving powers, have more than one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement 
$$\sqrt{4-3x} =x$$
can only be true when $x=1$

Comment: That's what I don't understand. How is it only true if x = 1. I have four possible solutions ( x = -1,1,-4,4) that when plugged in all get x=x.

Comment: @CollegeAnon The equation given has the principal root, without a $\pm$